# Yii 2 JSON_VALUE result as join condition in Active Record

Tags: json, activerecord, yii2

Example we have Table A and B.
In table A we have data field with some json data.

How to be build Active Record relation using `JSON_VALUE` condition?

In plain sql it would look like

```sql
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.id = JSON_VALUE(A.data, '$.paramName')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a findBySql  method

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM A
         LEFT JOIN B ON 'B.id = JSON_VALUE(A.data, " . $paramName . ")";
$model = YourModel::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

Comment: Its not that realy want, ofcause i can execute query via queryBuilder or createCommand, but i would like to find way via realation and/or joinWith/with methods in AR, ofcouse if its possible.

Comment: then yon build a normal join  and use the string format sintax for where  ..http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html

Comment: its seems i miss writen, result that i expect in output is $model->table_b, where $model is ActiveRecord and table_b populated relation via framework

Comment: just use the ModelClass you need  ..  or buil a relation in modeA for retrive the value form table B

Answer (score 0):

As far as i could find framework it self dosnot support sql function execution result as join relation. For now best way for me is to execute subqueries and use populateRelation method. ofcouse if youll find better way i would be glad to know.